# ANDROIDMK TRANSLATION ERROR: unsupported include in Android.bp

Tags: android, android-source, android-soong

Am trying to add the include fwk/base/pkgs/SettingsLib/common.mk onto Settings App, But am unsure how to use it on Android.bp file.

I used the **androidmk** conversion tool which comes with the AOSP build system to convert Android.mk to Android.bp

What I DID :

```
1. On AOSPSource code, check build/soong/androidmk and make full build.
2. After compiling the source code, the androidmk generation tool located :
# out/soong/host/linux-x86/bin/androidmk
3. Using the androidmk command try converting my Android.mk to Android.bp
# androidmk Android.mk > Android.bp
```

Error inside Android.bp

```
 20 // **ANDROIDMK TRANSLATION ERROR: unsupported include**
 21 // include frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/search/common.mk$
```

Any suggestions ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found way to convert Android.mk to Android.bp and import on App.

Core AOSP androidmk tool does NOT help, We need to manually create a SettingsLibDefaults on SettingsLibs ( create a Defaults on any libs) . [Referred AOSP SettingsLib Android.bp file](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/Android.bp;l=66).

```
// NOTE: Keep this module in sync with ./common.mk
java_defaults {
    name: "SettingsLibDefaults",
    static_libs: [
        "androidx.annotation_annotation",
        "androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-common",
        "androidx.legacy_legacy-support-v4",
        "androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-runtime",
        "androidx.recyclerview_recyclerview",
        "androidx.preference_preference",
        "androidx.appcompat_appcompat",
        "androidx.legacy_legacy-preference-v14",
        "SettingsLib",
    ],
}
```

Usage of SettingsLibDefaults on Settings App [Android.bp](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/apps/Settings/Android.bp;l=43;bpv=0;bpt=0) file

```
android_library {
    name: "Settings-core",
    platform_apis: true,
    defaults: [
        "SettingsLibDefaults",
        "SettingsLib-search-defaults",
    ],
```

Same way we need to create a Defaults on any libs Android.bp file and import on Apps.